# How to change React Native DateTime Picker locale for Android?

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am using [this](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) library to implement a `date picker` in my `React Native` app.

The only problem is that I have to change the language of the picker text.
For IOS it's working using `locale` prop but not working for Android.

For Android it's working only when changing the whole system language.

How can that be achievable please?

Answer (score 0):

in android device this component use the native component of date, the locale from component extends from device.
if you change the Locale/Language of your device the component extends this language.

You need go to your device config, and change Language/Local this will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).